# How to extract the assignment of "innerSort" from this expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sonarqube

- I have written a piece of code for sorting an array but getting error in sonarQube so I am not getting the issue

> Error: Extract the assignment of "innerSort" from this expression

```
    return innerSort=(a, b)=> {
      if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) return 0;
      const comparison = a[key].localeCompare(b[key]);
      return (
        (order === 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
      );
    };
  }
  module.exports = sortAlpha
```

Comment: What do you mean by extracting the assignment of innerSort? Do you want to export this function or something?

Comment: @Duc Nguyen I am also confused bcoz I am getting this in sonarQube

Comment: You're making me confused too, I don't see sonarQube anywhere in your code.